# C enum definition in struct with typedef

Tags: c, struct, enums, typedef

I found some problem with definition of enum inside a struct, I want to have something like:

```
typedef struct
{
    typedef enum { E1, E2, E3 } E;
    E e;
} S;
```

in VS2012 I have errors:

```
error C2071: 'E' : illegal storage class
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'E'
error C2059: syntax error : '}'
```

I found an explanation of C2071 but it is not the same case:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/deb3kh5w.aspx

gcc-4.9 says:

```
error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘typedef’
```

the interesting thing is that the code:

```
typedef enum { E1, E2, E3 } E;
E e;
```

works fine in global scope and in function's body.

I've also tried to do it without typedef, but unfortunately there are still lot's of errors:

```
error C2011: 'E' : 'enum' type redefinition
see declaration of 'E'
error C2208: 'E' : no members defined using this type
```

I found similar reason: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms927163.aspx
but I do define members of the type.

Comment: Any use of `typedef` in a structure declaration is a syntax error. What do you expect that code to do? If you want the `typedef` visible only inside the structure declaration (which isn't really useful anyway): Structure declarations don't introduce a new scope (and if they did, the enumeration constants would then be unreachable from outside the structure).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare your `enum` member like so:

```
typedef struct
{
    enum { E1, E2, E3 } e;
} S;
```

then you can do:

```
int main(void)
{
    S s;
    s.e = E1;

    /*  And so on  */
}
```